# Updating SQL Database Using VBA ADODB Connection

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I've been using ADODB for SQL queries to return data and copy it from a recordset to a workbook for a while and a new task is to update records but I have no clue on how to do update a record.

This is an example of my code:

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rec As ADODB.Recordset

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rec = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim sql As String

With con
    .Provider = "MSDASQL"
    .ConnectionString = "DSN=ukfast"
    .Open
End With

sql = "UPDATE crm_clients " & _
      "SET cheque_number = '" & chqNo & "' " & _
      "WHERE id = '' "
```

For Selecting data it was as easy as `recordset.copyFromRecordset`, but I have no clue about pushing an update back up to the database. I tried the `.update` method but that only works for the record set itself not the database. I've also looked for some sort of execute method but come up short.

What is the correct approach for updating a record using VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675023%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method of the connection object for that:

```
con.Execute(sql)
```